# Quantum measurement through entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, measurements

Lets assume I have a particle A which I want to measure it's spin. Based on what I have read about entanglement and measurement we can entangle a particle B with A so that B somehow registers(measures) particle A's spin. Can you describe the detail of the process in terms of bra-ket notation and also how we can extract such information from the final entangled state?

Comment: I've removed a comment discussion about site policy. However, in general, [please don't delete and re-ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168017/280545).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. You start off with your particle in the spin state
$$
|\psi⟩=\alpha\left|\uparrow\right> + \beta\left|\downarrow\right>,
$$
and you couple it to your pointer, which at the moment has a blank reading:
$$
|\psi⟩\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩=\alpha\left|\uparrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩ + \beta\left|\downarrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩.
$$
You then apply an entangling unitary $\hat U$ that takes the spin state and copies it onto the pointer,
\begin{align}
\hat U\left|\uparrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩ & = \left|\uparrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{up}⟩ \\
\hat U\left|\downarrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩& = \left|\downarrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{down}⟩,
\end{align}
so the state goes to
$$
\hat U|\psi⟩\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩=\alpha\left|\uparrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{up}⟩ + \beta\left|\downarrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{down}⟩,
$$
and finally you do a projective measurement on the pointer, which can project it onto the $|\mathrm{up}⟩$ pointer state, giving
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{p_\mathrm{up}}}(\mathbb I \otimes |\mathrm{up}⟩⟨\mathrm{up}|)\hat U|\psi⟩\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩= \left|\uparrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{up}⟩ 
$$
with probability $p_\mathrm{up}=|\alpha|^2$, or onto the $|\mathrm{down}⟩$ state, giving
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{p_\mathrm{down}}}(\mathbb I \otimes |\mathrm{down}⟩⟨\mathrm{down}|)\hat U|\psi⟩\otimes|\mathrm{blank}⟩=\left|\downarrow\right>\otimes|\mathrm{down}⟩ 
$$
with probability $p_\mathrm{down}=|\beta|^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. What would the blank state $|blank\rangle$ be if our pointer is another particle with two possible spins, namely $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$?

Comment: @user650585 It can be anything; the formalism in this answer is completely general.